# Can we combine convolution and higher powers for locally maximising a function?

Tags: limits, approximation, signal-processing, computational-mathematics

Can we somehow find local maximum function value (for strictly positive functions) using a convolution?

My idea is based on the result that $$ \lim_{p\to \infty}\left[\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N {(a_k)} ^p\right]^{\frac 1 p} = \max(a_k)$$

Similarly we might be able to use the result that

$$ \min(a_k) = \max(a_k)-\max(\max(a_k)-a_k)$$

Could we perhaps use this for building envelope detection? It seems theoretically sound to me, but would it be practically feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can do this.

If we consider the function $$f(t)=\cases{\frac 1 {2N}\phantom{0},|t|<N\\0\phantom{\frac 1 {2N}},|t|\geq N}$$

We can with the convolution

1. If we are in continuous time:

$$(g*f)(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(\tau)\cdot f(t-\tau) d\tau$$

2. If we are in discrete time:
   $$(g*f)(t)=\sum_{\tau=-\infty}^\infty g(\tau)\cdot f(t-\tau)$$

Define the non-linear operation $$O(g,p) = (g^p*f)(t)^{1/p}$$
Where exponent means multiplicative power.

For example: if $g(t) = \sin(t), O(g,4) = ((\sin(x)^4*f))(t)^{1/4}$

In practice we usually want much higher $p$ exponents, maybe 32 or 1024.

We now investigate the test-function

$$g(t) = \sin(60t^2)^2\cdot (\sin(16t)^2 + \cos(8t)^2)$$

The square is to get same level of minimum values: 0. 
If we analyze $g(t)$, we can see that we have a chirp function modulated by a slower wave. This is to investigate behaviors for different frequencies.

[image]

We see that for higher frequencies we get reasonable envelope behavior. It is also possible to observe that as we change parameter $N$ above, which frequency range we can calculate maxima for are affected - but also the rectangular shape of local maxima will grow. We may need to smooth these out somehow. But how to do so is outside scope of question.

Comment: Can you explain what you have plotted here? The red "max-envelope" curve can't be simply $g*f$, since that would give you the average value in a window rather than the maximum.

Comment: @Rahul yes you are right, I will correct.